Keykloack docker enable features
I'm having trouble enabling certain features in my custom Keycloak Docker image—specifically scripts, impersonation, and passkeys. Despite following the recommended steps, these features aren't available in the final image.What I've done:

Used multi-stage builds in my Dockerfile.
Ensured consistent Keycloak versions across all stages.
Activated preview features by setting KC_FEATURES=scripts,impersonation,passkeys.

A simplified version od my Dockerfile:

# Stage 1: Building Keycloak with features
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION} AS builder
ENV KC_FEATURES=scripts,impersonation,passkeys
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

# Stage 2: Final image
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/providers/ /opt/keycloak/providers/

CMD ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized", "--cache=ispn", "--verbose"]

The Issue:

When I check /opt/keycloak/providers/ in the running container, it only contains README.md.
When I run /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh show-config, it shows that the features are activated: kc.features = scripts,impersonation,passkeys (ENV)
However, the installed features in the logs don't list the additional features: Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-mysql, keycloak, logging-gelf, micrometer, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, vertx]
The "Script Mapper" option is missing in the admin console.

Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to properly include these features in the final image?

/opt/keycloak/providers/ is the path for custom providers (JAR files), and the /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/ path is the directory that contains the stuff after the build, therefore
# Stage 1: Building Keycloak with features
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION} AS builder

# If you have custom providers
COPY /service-providers-jars /opt/keycloak/providers/ 

ENV KC_FEATURES=scripts,impersonation,passkeys
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

# Stage 2: Final image
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
# copy the whole /opt/keycloak/
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

CMD ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized", "--cache=ispn", "--verbose"]

Or if you want, the COPY line can be in the for of
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/providers/ /opt/keycloak/providers/
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/ /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/


After further investigation, I copied the entire built version during my trial and error tests, and the passkey feature is working fine.
Coincidentally, I initially checked the scripts feature in the same way as the example you provided, even before realizing they had suggested it. It seems the issue isn't with feature availability, but specifically with scripts:v1, which appears to be missing. I haven't been able to find any updated documentation for this feature.
If someone have any insights on that feature availability, don't hesitate !

so if copy the whole build has fixed the issue, you may accept the answer.
